# Delphi Barcode Reader Code

Tags: delphi, open-source, barcode

Anyone know of an opensource Barcode reader for Delphi, that reads barcodes from a webcam?

Comment: while the site did not exist way back when this question was asked, today it would be a perfect candidate for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Btw, I just bought a USB barcode reader for under USD 20, so there's not much reason for scanning barcodes from a webcam . A lot has changed in the 8 years sicen this questoin was asked :-)

Comment: I agree and that is what I used myself in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a webcam with a good resolution for reading barcodes.
If you know how to call C/C++ code from delphi, you should look into the [zebra barcode reader](http://zebra.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

1. Barcodes recognition: **[J4L](http://www.java4less.com/vision/vision.php?info=GuideDelphi)**
2. Barcodes generation: **[TurboPower SysTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools/)**

Answer (score 1):

I use dtk barcode sdk from http://www.dtksoft.com/.  It is neither free nor open source though so it may not fit your needs.  It comes as a dll and it was easy to write a delphi wrapper around it.

Basically, you pass it a file (image or pdf) and it returns the number and contents of the barcodes in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that's a DLL/ActiveX(albeit not free) that apparently comes with an example that reads from a webcam. There's also a free command line version but it's not quite as feature rich. Haven't used it, but it's been on my radar for a while.

http://www.inspirant.de/index.php?ref=prodinbarcodeocr&lg=en

Colin

Answer (score 0):

its is possible, [barcodepedia](http://en.barcodepedia.com/) have flash reader that reads barcodes from a webcam.

but looking at the site it looks like they are not into giving away the reader.

something that keeps coming up in google is [Eym Barcode Reader](http://www.metois.com/Eymbarcode/eymbcdemo.htm) which is an ActiveX/OCX

Comment: I found that, you can embed it in your own website, its in flash though.  He seems to be givign the source of the flash app though.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose from many Java BarcodeReader libraries and use it with JIntend object.